Customtkinter widgets has white background when loaded
could not find solution, so posting my issue.
In my application I have set appearance mode to "System" and it loads correct theme but widgets have white background and corners.
Loading with different appearance mode
Mouse over fixes button text background, but not corners. I have implemented work around which fixes issue:
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")

it loads in different mode then switches to my desired "System".
loads like this
I don't like this approach and would like to understand and fix this issue. What could cause this issue?

Did you set the label and button's background to the same as the window? customtkinter widgets always will have these because tkinter widgets are square.
Alternatively, you can try using a interface creator website por customtkinter like customtkbuilder.com
